# how to extract numeric information from a string in Pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe that contains **string** rows such as :

```
'(0.0,0.8638888888888889,3.7091666666666665,12.023333333333333,306.84694444444443)'
```

This output (produced by another program) corresponds to the min, 25th, median, 75th and max for a given variable.

I would like to extract that information, and put them in separate **numeric** columns, such as

```
min   p25    p50
0.0   0.864  3.70
```

The data I have is really large. How can I do that in Pandas?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried upon, and the problem area.

Comment: Is it pandas or python?

Comment: Won't this just be `df[['min','p25','p50']] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0],x[1],x[2]))`? Also what you've shown is a tuple with integers but your title says strings so which is it? Can you post raw data and code

Comment: hi edchum, the column in a string unfortunately. so using your code does not work

Comment: the downvotes are not justified in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC then the following should work:

```
In [280]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['(0.0,0.8638888888888889,3.7091666666666665,12.023333333333333,306.84694444444443)']})
df

Out[280]:
                                                 col
0  (0.0,0.8638888888888889,3.7091666666666665,12....

In [297]:
df[['min','p25','p50']] = df['col'].str.replace('\'|\(|\)','').str.split(',', expand=True).astype(np.float64)[[0,1,2]]
df

Out[297]:
                                                 col  min       p25       p50
0  (0.0,0.8638888888888889,3.7091666666666665,12....  0.0  0.863889  3.709167
```

So this replaces the `'` `(` and `)` characters with blank using [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and then we split using [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) on the comma and cast the type to float and then index the cols of interest.